# Get jquery formatted value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div like this :

```
<td id="length" data-length=<?php echo $length;?> >
```

And I want to get the value of my php variable ($length) in a jquery script.

After that I have to format it to replace the comma with point.

With this snippet :

```
var $length         = jQuery(this).find("#length");
console.log($length.data('length'));
```

I  see read my variable in the console

but when I want to format it to replace the comma with a point like this  :

```
console.log(parseFloat($length.val().replace(",", ".")));
```

I get NaN

Please help to solve that problem !

Comment: Why do you use `$length.val()` even though you correctly extracted the data with `$length.data('length')` the line above. .val() should be used for forms elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your missing the quotes around the value of data-length. Correct your HTML markup like this:

```
<td id="length" data-length="<?php echo $length;?>" >
```

Next, you do not want `val()` you want `data('length')`

```
console.log(parseFloat($length.data('length').replace(",", ".")));
```

Comment: This returns an error: 
 length.data("length").replace is not a function !!

Comment: The source of my problem was that I have differents types in my variable : numbers and string ; 
I have solved the problem like this : 
`var $length = jQuery(this).find(".length").data('length').toString().replace(",", ".");`
Thanks to all :)

Answer (score 1):

You're using `.val()` on a `<td>` instead of `.data()`.

```
 // Here you're using .data()
console.log($length.data('length'));

 // Here you're using .val() which is wrong.
console.log(parseFloat($length.val().replace(",", ".")));
```

Comment: @Bizboss: Well if `.data('length')` was working for you, and switching to `.val()` causes it to not work...

Comment: @Bizboss: Oh, I see from another comment that you're reusing IDs on a page. That's invalid. I guess I could have guessed you were doing that when you had `jQuery(this).find("#length");` instead of just `jQuery("#length");`. To reuse like you are, you need to use `class="length` for your elements instead of `id="length"`. As far as how to select the proper one, that will depend on your markup, but try `var $length = jQuery(this).find(".length");` after switching to classes.

Answer (score 1):

If your `$length` variable's value in PHP will be output containing a comma, the first thing you have to do is correct your markup:

```
<td id="length" data-length="<?php echo $length;?>" >
```

You need the quotes, so the result looks like this to the browser:

```
<td id="length" data-length="1,23" >
```

Then:

```
var $length         = jQuery(this).find("#length");
console.log(parseFloat($length.data("length").replace(",", ".")));
```

...should give you "1.23" in the log (given my example value above).

---

Perhaps worth noting: I'd avoid using the `id` value "length". That's just too common a word, and unfortunately the `id` namespace gets cluttered up with *all sorts of things*, particularly on IE. I'd go for something more unique.

Comment: I get the following error :
length.data("length").replace is not a function

Comment: Look at the markup in the browser, the problem should be pretty easy to spot. Fundamentally, it works: http://jsbin.com/ilaqiq

Comment: For instance, are you absolutely sure that there's only *one* element on the page with the `id` "length"? Remember that `id`s **must** be unique on the page.

Comment: Ah yes, I think that's my problem, I have several instance if elements the same id (lenght). How can I solve that ??

Comment: @Bizboss: Give them different `id`s. `id` values **must** be unique: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't quite right, you're trying to replace the comma in the jQuery object containing the `td#length` element, try this:

```
var length = $("#length").data("length");
console.log(parseFloat(length.replace(",",".");
```

Also, your HTML should include quotes around the value of each attribute, like this:

```
<td id="length" data-length="<?php echo $length;?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(parseFloat($length.attr("data-length").replace(",", ".")));`